# Customize Woo Subscriptions End date

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I use the plugin Woo Subscriptions for payment in installments on wordpress, my concern is that instead of being considered as a split payment for example in 2 installments, it is rather considered as a subscription of 2 months in the invoice, so in the invoice instead of :
1st payment March 19
2nd payment April 12

on the current invoice it's :
Start date: March 19
End date: May 19

which doesn't make sense for my customers because it looks like it's divided into 3 (March, April, May)

I've already tried a filter but it didn't work to change the end date.